# laravel 5.3 image upload link

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.3

I'm creating an app using the laravel framework for php. I've created a very simple image upload function like this-

in the form i use a multipart/form-data form and pass it to this controller-

```
$path = $request->file('photo')->store('public/photos');
return view('auth.newPortfolio',compact('path'));
```

Everything works as expected. Photos are added to the storage/app/public/photos directory and I used

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to create a symbolic link to the storage directory. When I return the path to the view above it is an absolute path to the storage/app/public/photos directory rather than the relative path that is accessible from the application. Right now I'm remaking the link by running-

```
$newimage = explode('/', $image); $publishimage = last($newimage);
```

$publishimage holds just the name of the image and so I add storage/photos/ to the front of the image name to get a link that will show the image. Something like-

```
src="/storage/photos{{$publishimage}}"
```

My question is this- is there a helper function or something that does this for me? I feel like this is kinda a hacky solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use public_path() function, it  returns the fully qualified path to the public directory.

```
    src="{{ public_path('images/' . $publishimage) }}"
```

[method-public_path laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-public-path)